# Convert Java long to int64 in C++

Tags: java, c++, int, type-conversion, long-integer

I am receiving some numerical data from a Java client via socket connection on C++ server. When I receive 4 byte int type data, what I need is just using ntohl() function or reverse the bit order to convert to c++ int type. However, I'am having trouble trying to convert long data type from Java. No matter what I tried, I could not recover the correct value. I used LONG64, ULONG64 and int64_t as well, and none of them worked.

For example, when I send long s = 1 from Java,  on C++ side I did:

```
int64_t size;
recv(client, (char *)&size, sizeof int64_t, 0);
```

if I do

```
size = ntohl(size)
```

Then size will become 0 whatever the original long value is in Java !

If I don't do ntohl() conversion, then size = 72057594037927936 for s = 1

I have hardly found any useful information on this topic and I would appreciate any  suggestion.

Comment: Just for clarity, on what architecture is a 4-byte int type data occupying *64 bits* ? Last I checked, **4** bytes is nearly always 4 octets = **32** bits. You know you could always (a) read them into an `int8_t ar[n]` and actually verify the number of bytes-read and validate where they are in the sequence. Verifying the return result of `recv` couldn't hurt either.

Comment: Java, unlike C and C++ for instance, doesn't care about endianness; it will alway be big endian. Isn't that the source of your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. As said by Rob in the answer, the problem is on ntohl() function itself, it operates on 32 bit data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value 72057594037927936 is 0x0100000000000000 in Hex.  As you may have guessed, that's simply backwards byte ordering, the 1 is in front instead of back.

ntohl() is 32-bit, so it is throwing out those top four bytes (the first 8 hex digits), giving you zero.  You could possibly use htonll instead, but that isn't quite right.  The best thing is to reverse the order of the bytes yourself.

```
int64_t size;
recv(client, (char *)&size, sizeof int64_t, 0);
char *start = (char *)&size, *end = start + sizeof(size);
std::reverse(start, end);
```

There are a ton of ways of reversing the bytes, and a ton of ways of dealing with little/big endian problems in general.

Comment: Clear and straightforward. Thank you very much sir!